# Changing view of a table : rows to columns

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite

I am writing a program to schedule timetable of a school. I am using `QSQLITE` and c++ in Qt.

I have a table as shown below. The values are given by the user.

```
+------+------+------------------+
| day  | hour | sub              |
+------+------+------------------+
| Mon  |    1 | Maths            |
| Mon  |    2 | Physics          |
| Mon  |    3 | Chemistry        |
| Tue  |    1 | Biology          |
| Tue  |    2 | P.H.E            |
| Tue  |    3 | Computer Science |
| Wed  |    1 | Physics          |
| Wed  |    2 | Chemistry Lab    |
| Wed  |    3 | Chemistry Lab    |
+------+------+------------------+
```

I would like to change the view to something like this :

```
+------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+
| day  |    1     |    2            |          3          |
+------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+
| Mon  |  Maths   |   Physics       |   Chemistry         |
| Tue  |  Biology |   P.H.E         |   Computer Science  |
| Wed  |  Physics |   Chemistry Lab |   Chemistry Lab     |
+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Is it possible is any way ?

NOTE : If it's not possible by only using SQL commands, I am Ok with C++.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select day,
       max(case when hour = 1 then sub end) as hour_1,
       max(case when hour = 2 then sub end) as hour_2,
       max(case when hour = 3 then sub end) as hour_3
from t
group by day;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a problem. Using max() , it provides only one value. There are 2 or more subjects at the same time (ex : diff batches for labs ), I could not find any function like CONCAT() on sqlite. So , is there any way I can concatenate those values  ( comma separated)  instead of max () ?

Comment: Thought it would be better asked as a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/40688895/5898324